# Integral substitution for Maxwells perfect gas as a pdf

Tags: integration, substitution

I'm going working through mathematical statistics by Larsen, and he provides the example of the expected value of the pdf for Maxwells infamous perfect gas equation:

$f_s(s) = 4\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\pi}}s^2e^{-as^2}$

I'm unsure of how he derives the integral substitution for the equation here:
$2m\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\pi}}\int_0^\infty s^4 e^{-as^2}ds$

after taking the sbustitution $t=as^2$

he gets:

$E(W) = \frac{m}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty t^{\frac{3}{2}}e^-t\space dt$

Perhaps I'm a bit rusty with my substitution but I couldn't seem to derive his answer after implementing the substitution, any help on how it's properly implemented is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Step by step...

$$2m\sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}s^4e^{-as^2}ds$$

setting $t=as^2$

that means also

$$dt=2asds$$

you can rewrite you integral in the following form

$$m\frac{a^{3/2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{(as^2)^{3/2}}{a^{3/2}}e^{-as^2}\frac{2asds}{a}$$

and simplifying...

$$\frac{m}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}t^{3/2}e^{-t}dt=\frac{m}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)=\frac{3m}{4a}$$

Comment: Could you explain in a little more detail how the second form is achieved? That's where I seem to be struggling

Comment: @Stackbeans :It's just a factorization in order to get the integrand in function of $t=as^2$.

First observe that, differentiating you get $dt=2as ds$ thus you have to split $s^4$ in $s^3\times s$ because "one $s$" is to be included in $dt$

Then attach the needed constants in order to have all the integrand expressed in $f(as^2)$